# Roland Quad-capture doesn't works

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, soundcard, external-soundcard

All audio tracks and videos don't start playing. It shows in `pavucontrol` as `QUAD-CAPTURE Analog Surround 4.0`, and I can select it as fallback audio output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch card to 44.100 kHz mode. That's possible from MS Windows quad-capture driver. Then reboot to ubuntu again.

It allows to use device for output, but input still not available